# Laravel 5.1 Ajax call for 'Like' system not happening

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am building an application where users can upload projects. I am implementing a system where users can 'Like/Unlike' other projects. I am trying to use an AJAX call to save likes. Users are able to like projects on the detail page of a project (/projects/{id})

I have a table users, projects and likes. My plan is to save the likes in the likes table obviously so a record looks like this: id, user_id, project_id. In the future I can do a COUNT query and find out how many likes each project has, etc.

Currently nothing happens when I click on the like button I get no errors, nothing happens.

My files:
Routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'LikeController@index');
Route::post('projects/{id}', 'LikeController@like');
```

LikeController.php:

```
public function like()
{
    if(Request::ajax()) {
        $data = Input::all();
        print_r($data);die;
    }
}
```

My view: show.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'projects/'.$project->id.'/like','method'=>'POST', 'id'=>'myform')) !!}
{!! Form::button('Like', array('class'=>'send-btn')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My AJAX call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.send-btn').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'projects',
                type: "post",
                data: {'user_id': $('input[name=user_id]').val(), 'project_id': $('input[name=project_id]').val()},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript for the ajax call? Please share the javascript as well.

Comment: Do you have error reporting and debugging in Laravel turned on?

Comment: @Aakash Edited OP, forgot to add it sorry!

Comment: @Satisfaction Yes, I have.

Comment: Is the route being triggered? What's the result you get when debugging the AJAX request? (in Firebug or Chrome Dev tools or similar)

Comment: I get this error POST http://xyz/projects/projects 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: your url in javascript is just projects but your route is projects/{id}

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax function you have an option `url: 'projects'`. This means your ajax call will be sent to the relative `projects` path. To fix this, change it to `url: '/projects'`.

Also your route includes an id of the project `projects/{id}`, so you have to add it to your ajax call option too.

```
$('.send-btn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).parent().attr('action'),
        type: "post",
        data: {'user_id': $('input[name=user_id]').val(), 'project_id': $('input[name=project_id]').val()},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I add the id to the url in my ajax call?

Comment: Updated my answer. Take an actual url from the `action` form's attribute. Also look at @DeveloperatAditmicrosys answer too. May be your route url is not right too.

Comment: I understand your method and changed it but I still get the 500 (Internal Server Error) error in my console. I found something about a token that I have to add to my ajax call?

Comment: Yes, you may have to add CSFR protection token to your request http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection Or just remove this check from your ajax call http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: I added the token and now when I press the button It gets stuck "loading" the button stays in active state and the site is stuck. I can't even f5. No errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

as per your form action you need to change route,

Like this.

```
Route::post('projects/{id}/like', 'LikeController@like');
```

Instead of this one

```
Route::post('projects/{id}', 'LikeController@like');
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an AJAX request, when you submit the form you should prevent the default event and then make a request, like so:

```
$('#form-id').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stops the form from being submited the normal way.

    $.ajax({
        url: 'projects',
        type: "post",
        data: {'user_id': $('input[name=user_id]').val(), 'project_id': $('input[name=project_id]').val()}
    })
    .done(function(response) { 
        //handle response on success
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
        //handle failed request
    });
});
```

You will also need to change the url to the correct path, the way it is set in your routes.php file.

Comment: I changed it and still nothing happens not even an error in my console

Comment: For all your ajax requests, if you have enabled the csrf protection middleware, you will also need to send a token. [link](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection)

Comment: I added the token and now when I press the button It gets stuck "loading" the button stays in active state and the site is stuck. I can't even f5. No errors or warnings.

Comment: Can you add `console.log(xhr.responseJSON)` in the .fail() callback function? You should be able to see the error in console then.

Comment: When I use your method nothing happens I click the button and get no error or nothing in my console

Comment: Shouldn't I add something in the .done function? My goal is to save the data in the databank. I don't see how this is happening at the moment

Comment: After the request finishes a response is sent with a status code and response object. If the status code is 200 the .done function is fired. Every other status code (like 500) will fire the .fail function. the `console.log(xhr.responseJSON)` is purely for debug purposes. Try it and see what errors pop up so you can fix them.

Comment: I added it and nothing happens no error in my console there's nothing :'(

Comment: Is the id of the form correctly written? In my example is #form-id you may need to change that. Check to see if the submit event is fired or not.

Comment: I did change it. I did a console.log after the submit but it doesnt get logged in my console so the submit isn't working?

Comment: It is possible. Try add `alert('something');` before the `e.preventDefault();` just to see if it fires the event or not.

Comment: Tried it and doesn't work. This means the submit is not happening?

Comment: Yes, make sure the form id is the correct one. In your example is **myform**. Note that it should be the id of the form not the submit button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93810/discussion-between-filipnikolovski-and-moussa-chaabar).

Comment: Can we continue the discussion any time soon? Thanks in advance!